# How to rotate image in CSS/html

Tags: html, css, image

on my website I have a gallery with some pics of my girlfriend and me, but there are two pics that are displayed upside down.
And I don't know why. All other pics are perfect.
Every picture is shot by the same iPhone 7+ but first two pictures are upside down on the website. On my computer they are displayed perfectly.

Here is the Website: www.selinaundleon.com/gallery.html
Can someone help me with this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Open in an image editor and re-save. The metadata is confusing the browser (the image is saved upside-down and the metadata says so, but the browser doesn't always like it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and attach a class to the images (`<img>` elements) to rotate, using [`transform`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property):

```css
.rotate-180 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="100"/>
<img class="rotate-180" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="100"/>
```

**Note:** I recommend to resave the images rotated with a image software of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, but the picture doesn't rotate anyway in my case.

Comment: transform on inline element should not work ... but for image it does